# CodeIgniter 3 Unable to extend library on live server

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, extend

I extends CI_pagination in MY_pagination library. its working fine offline in wamp. But i dont know why it is not working online on live server.

MY_pagination.php

```
    <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class MY_pagination extends CI_pagination {
        protected $CI;

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
                // reference to the CodeIgniter super object
            $this->CI =& get_instance();

         }



         public function table_pagination($page_url, $total_rows, $per_page)
        {

            $config = array(
                'base_url' => $page_url,
                'total_rows' => $total_rows,
                'per_page' => $per_page,
                'use_page_numbers' => TRUE,
                'num_links' => 2,

                'next_link' => 'Next',
                'prev_link' => 'Previous',
                'reuse_query_string' => true,
                'first_link' => false,
                'last_link' => false,

                'full_tag_open' => '<ul class="pagination">',
                'full_tag_close' => '</ul>',
                'next_tag_open' => '<li class="paginate_button next" id="example1_next">',
                'next_tag_close' => '</li>',
                'prev_tag_open' => '<li class="paginate_button previous" id="example1_previous">',
                'prev_tag_close' => '</li>',
                'cur_tag_open' => '<li class="paginate_button active"><a>',
                'cur_tag_close' => '</a></li>',
                'num_tag_open' => '<li class="paginate_button">',
                'num_tag_close' => '</li>'
            );

            $this->CI->pagination->initialize($config);
            return $this->CI->pagination->create_links();


        }

     public function home_pagination($page_url, $total_rows, $per_page)
        {

            $config = array(
                 'prefix' => 'page/',
                'base_url' => $page_url,
                'total_rows' => $total_rows,
                'per_page' => $per_page,
                'use_page_numbers' => TRUE,
                'num_links' => 2,

                'next_link' => '<img src="'.base_url('assets/images/arrow-next-small.png').'" alt=""/>',
                'prev_link' => '<img src="'.base_url('assets/images/arrow-pre-small.png').'" alt=""/>',
                'reuse_query_string' => true,
                'first_link' => false,
                'last_link' => false,

                'full_tag_open' => '<div class="pagination">',
                'full_tag_close' => '</div>',
                'next_tag_open' => '',
                'next_tag_close' => '',
                'prev_tag_open' => '',
                'prev_tag_close' => '',
                'cur_tag_open' => '<a href="#" class="active">',
                'cur_tag_close' => '</a>',
                'num_tag_open' => '',
                'num_tag_close' => ''
            );

            $this->CI->pagination->initialize($config);
            return $this->CI->pagination->create_links();


        }

    }
```

Home_controller.php

```
<?php
class Home_controller extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->helper('date');
        $this->load->helper('main');
        $this->load->helper('cookie');
        $this->load->helper('template_helper');
        $this->load->helper('db_helper');
        $remember_me = get_cookie('user_remember');
        _session_login($remember_me);
        $this->load->library('session');

        // _valid_session_login_check();
        //  $this->load->model('admin_models/sliders/slider_model');

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $controller_base_url = base_url("/front_controllers/home/home_controller/index");
        $controller_re_url   = base_url("/index");
        $uri_values          = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(2);
        $search_string       = "";
        if (isset($uri_values['search'])) {
            $search_string = $uri_values['search'];
        }

        $page_num = 1;
        if (isset($uri_values['page'])) {
            $page_num = $uri_values['page'];
        }

        $page_url = $controller_re_url;
        if ($search_string !== "") {
            $page_url = $page_url . "/search/" . $search_string;
        }

        if (!isset($uri_values['search'])) {
            $search_string = $this->input->get('search');
        }

        $per_page = 12;
        if ($search_string == "") {
            $post_list  = _get_post_list($per_page, $page_num);
            $total_rows = _post_rows_count("active", "");
        } else {
            $post_list  = _post_search($search_string, $per_page, $page_num);
            $total_rows = _home_search_rows_count($search_string);
        }

        $active_post_pagination = $this->pagination->home_pagination($page_url, $total_rows, $per_page);
        $cat_list               = _get_term_list_post_count('category', 0, 1);
        $tag_list               = _get_term_list_post_count('tag', 10, 1);

        // print_r($post_list);

        $urls       = array(
            'controller_base_url' => $controller_base_url,
            'controller_re_url' => $controller_re_url
        );
        $this->data = array(
            'urls' => $urls,
            'post_list' => $post_list,
            'widget_cat_list' => $cat_list,
            'widget_tag_list' => $tag_list,
            'active_post_pagination' => $active_post_pagination
        );
        $this->meta = 'layout/front_layout/normal_meta';
        $this->head = 'layout/front_layout/home/home_view_head_section';
        $this->body = 'layout/front_layout/home/home_view_content_section';
        $this->layout();
    }
}

?>
```

Error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Pagination::home_pagination() in /home/lovebatth39/public_html/application/controllers/front_controllers/home/Home_controller.php on line 55

I dont know why its not working online.  Mainly I am trying to extend pagination library. I already checked Naming system like capital `MY_`

`$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';`

Config file also set to `MY_`

CI ignoring `MY_pagination.php` or `MY_pagination.php` completely on live server no matter what I put on file

Comment: Try with `$this->initialize($config);` and `$this->create_links();` instead. Class extending is already gives you full object of CI_Pagination.

Comment: Where is the file `MY_Pagination.php` ?

Comment: Try reading the documentation before posting a question:  https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming  ~ You can actually read the entire online manual in a few hours including the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rename pagination library file to `MY_Pagination.php` and change the line below :

```
class MY_pagination extends CI_pagination {
```

To

```
class MY_Pagination extends CI_Pagination {
```

Comment: Its working now thanks , i renamed the file also, i think all things are case senstive

Comment: Quote @LovepreetSinghBatth, *"i think all things are case senstive"*  ~ no kidding!  [Try reading the documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming)

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers indicate you're using improper file and class naming. In addition you have structured `MY_Pagination` incorrectly. Because it extends a class all the properties and methods of that base class are available.

Here's the way file should be defined. Pay attention to **where** this file is stored and to the class declaration line capitalization.

file: **/application/libraries/MY_Pagination.php**

```
<?php

if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Pagination extends CI_Pagination
{
// $CI and __construct() are not needed here. The parent class has them 
//  protected $CI;
//
//  public function __construct()
//  {
//      parent::__construct();
//      // reference to the CodeIgniter super object
//      $this->CI = & get_instance();
//  }

    public function table_pagination($page_url, $total_rows, $per_page)
    {
        $config = array(
            'base_url' => $page_url,
            'total_rows' => $total_rows,
            'per_page' => $per_page,
            'use_page_numbers' => TRUE,
            'num_links' => 2,
            'next_link' => 'Next',
            'prev_link' => 'Previous',
            'reuse_query_string' => true,
            'first_link' => false,
            'last_link' => false,
            'full_tag_open' => '<ul class="pagination">',
            'full_tag_close' => '</ul>',
            'next_tag_open' => '<li class="paginate_button next" id="example1_next">',
            'next_tag_close' => '</li>',
            'prev_tag_open' => '<li class="paginate_button previous" id="example1_previous">',
            'prev_tag_close' => '</li>',
            'cur_tag_open' => '<li class="paginate_button active"><a>',
            'cur_tag_close' => '</a></li>',
            'num_tag_open' => '<li class="paginate_button">',
            'num_tag_close' => '</li>'
        );

        //initialize() and create_links() are part of "this" class
        $this->initialize($config);
        return $this->create_links();
    }

    public function home_pagination($page_url, $total_rows, $per_page)
    {

        $config = array(
            'prefix' => 'page/',
            'base_url' => $page_url,
            'total_rows' => $total_rows,
            'per_page' => $per_page,
            'use_page_numbers' => TRUE,
            'num_links' => 2,
            'next_link' => '<img src="'.base_url('assets/images/arrow-next-small.png').'" alt=""/>',
            'prev_link' => '<img src="'.base_url('assets/images/arrow-pre-small.png').'" alt=""/>',
            'reuse_query_string' => true,
            'first_link' => false,
            'last_link' => false,
            'full_tag_open' => '<div class="pagination">',
            'full_tag_close' => '</div>',
            'next_tag_open' => '',
            'next_tag_close' => '',
            'prev_tag_open' => '',
            'prev_tag_close' => '',
            'cur_tag_open' => '<a href="#" class="active">',
            'cur_tag_close' => '</a>',
            'num_tag_open' => '',
            'num_tag_close' => ''
        );

        $this->initialize($config);
        return $this->create_links();
    }
}
```

In the controller `$this->load->library('pagination');` will recognize that `MY_pagination.php` exists and will load it. Using `$this->load->library('my_pagination');` will fail.

As a side note, the name of your controller is clumsy. Just use this

```
class Home extends MY_Controller
```

The you can use URLs like `https://example.com/home` instead of `https://example.com/home_controller`. Which, IMO, looks dumb.

Comment: This is a great answer.  However, the OP should be reading the online docs and doing the tutorial, where much of this is clearly spelled out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change names `MY_pagination` to `MY_Pagination` and `CI_pagination` to `CI_Pagination`.
2. Change `$this->load->library('pagination');` to `$this->load->library('my_pagination');`

Comment: I tried but not working error Unable to load the requested class: My_pagination